# Hibernate StaleDataException while merge

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I have 2 web-service APIs. In one api, I fetch an entity and return in as an SRO.
I another api, I receive an SRO, convert it into an entity and use

```
sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().merge(code);
```

However, I get the following exception. Please help me find the reason for same.

```
org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateOptimisticLockingFailureException: Object of class [PartnerPromoCode] with identifier [254874]: optimistic locking failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.StaleObjectStateException: Row was updated or deleted by another transaction (or unsaved-value mapping was incorrect): [PartnerPromoCode#254874]
at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.SessionFactoryUtils.convertHibernateAccessException(SessionFactoryUtils.java:683)
at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateExceptionTranslator.convertHibernateAccessException(HibernateExceptionTranslator.java:89)
at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateExceptionTranslator.translateExceptionIfPossible(HibernateExceptionTranslator.java:68)
at org.springframework.dao.support.ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.translateExceptionIfPossible(ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.java:58)
at org.springframework.dao.support.DataAccessUtils.translateIfNecessary(DataAccessUtils.java:213)
at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:163)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:155)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:199)
at sun.proxy.$Proxy48.updatePartnerPromoCode(Unknown Source)
at abc.updatePartnerPromoCode(abc.java:567)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:616)
at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:307)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:183)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:150)
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:110)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:199)
at sun.proxy.$Proxy54.updatePartnerPromoCode(Unknown Source)
at abc.updatePartnerPromoCode(ServiceDealWebServiceController.java:272)
at xyz$$FastClassByCGLIB$$c65431c6.invoke(<generated>)
at net.sf.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:149)
```

**EDIT**

Here is the entity
@Entity
@Table(name = "partner_promo_code", catalog = "snapdeal")
@NamedQueries({
        @NamedQuery(name = QueryNames.GET_UNUSED_PARTNER_PROMO_CODE, query = "select p from PartnerPromoCode p where p.status=0 and p.partnerCode = :partnerCode and p.catalogId = :catalogId order by p.id"),
        @NamedQuery(name = QueryNames.GET_PARTNER_PROMO_CODE_BY_PROMO, query = "from PartnerPromoCode  where partnerCode = :partnerCode and promoCode = :promoCode") })
public class PartnerPromoCode implements java.io.Serializable {

```
public static final Boolean STATUS_USED      = true;
public static final Boolean STATUS_NOT_USED  = false;
/**
 * 
 */
private static final long   serialVersionUID = 7786688992136091701L;
private Integer             id;
private String              partnerCode;
private String              promoCode;
private Boolean             status;
private Date                expiry;
private Date                created;
private Date                updated;

public PartnerPromoCode() {
}

public PartnerPromoCode(String partnerCode, String promoCode) {
    this.partnerCode = partnerCode;
    this.promoCode = promoCode;
    this.status = STATUS_NOT_USED;
}

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = IDENTITY)
@Column(name = "id", unique = true, nullable = false)
public Integer getId() {
    return this.id;
}

public void setId(Integer id) {
    this.id = id;
}

@Column(name = "partner_code")
public String getPartnerCode() {
    return partnerCode;
}

public void setPartnerCode(String partnerCode) {
    this.partnerCode = partnerCode;
}

@Column(name = "promo_code")
public String getPromoCode() {
    return promoCode;
}

public void setPromoCode(String promoCode) {
    this.promoCode = promoCode;
}

@Column(name = "status")
public Boolean getStatus() {
    return status;
}

public void setStatus(Boolean status) {
    this.status = status;
}

@Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
@Column(name = "expiry", nullable = false, length = 19)
public Date getExpiry() {
    return expiry;
}

public void setExpiry(Date expiry) {
    this.expiry = expiry;
}

@Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
@Column(name = "created", nullable = false, length = 19)
public Date getCreated() {
    return created;
}

public void setCreated(Date created) {
    this.created = created;
}

@Version
@Column(name = "updated", nullable = false, length = 19)
public Date getUpdated() {
    return updated;
}

public void setUpdated(Date updated) {
    this.updated = updated;
}
```

}

I am fetching entity by id and converting it into an SRO,,,passing it over the wire...then later on i receive the sro, create a new entity object and set the id and every other fields, set the updated field to current time and then try to merge the entity through `sessionFactory.getSession().merge(obj)`

Answer (score 0):

Because the value of the field annotated with `@Version` doesn't match with the value stored in the database (or because the row in the database doesn't exist anymore).

Comment: there no field with annotation @Version in my entity class. Also the row exists. Strangely enough, if i write HQL query to update the table, it works perfectly well but hibernate merge / update operations fail of this entity class. What could be the reason.

Comment: Show us the code and the mapping of PartnerPromoCode (and all its superclasses). HQL update queries completely bypass optimistic locking.

Comment: Hi Nizet, You are right. There is a @Version annotation in the entity class.     //@Version
    //@Column(name = "updated", nullable = false, length = 19)
    public Date getUpdated() {
        return updated;
    }
However, I am also updating the timestamp while merging.

Comment: What do you mean by "updating the timestamp"? If you set its value to the current time, then it's wrong. Its value should be the one you got when loading the entity, in order for Hibernate to check if the entity has been modified by someone else since the time you loaded it.